# How to refactor my code in AsyncTask without runOnUiThread?

Tags: android, json, api, android-asynctask

Hello android developers! I have one problem with compatibility of my old codes and API 18.
All codes bellow runs perfectly in android 2.3. But when I try to run it on a newer API it crashes. Can I use it without runOnUiThread for updating my UI? What I shoud change? Thanks!

```
class GetDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(QueryProduct.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                int success;
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
                        tvName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));

                    }else{

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error that your "codes" is giving you?

Comment: `NetworkOnMain` no doubt

Comment: with the current code you create a new thread for nothing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
class GetDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(QueryProduct.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

// Do your Background Task Inside it and inside it when you want to update the Ui 
// then call the method publishProgress. this call the method onProgressUpdate that 
// run on the UI thread and inside it you update your UI
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {



            int success;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT);

                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                    String result = product.getString(tvName)
                   // Need To Update the Ui so call the method publishProgress(result );
                   // this will call  onProgressUpdate(String... values)  method and                                      
                   // String result i provide it to  so that i can update the text view                           
                   // in it.

                   //Update  in publish progress you can specify multiple String values
                   // and same received in onProgressUpdate as an array of values.
                   //publishProgress("value1","value2","value3")
                    publishProgress(result,"result2","result3");

                }else{

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    return null;
}
// run on the Ui thread so inside it you can update your UI
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
        {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
      tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
      tvName.setText(values[0]);

      tvPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
      tvPrice.setText(values[1]); 
      tvAdress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAdress);
      tvAdress .setText(values[2]); 
      }
     protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

      pDialog.dismiss();
   }
```

}

Comment: you can't access to `product`, you need return that from `doInBackground`

Comment: Mind explaining to the OP and future visitors what you have done and why this should work?

Comment: Answer without any explanation wont helpful for future , here we are not for this OP. You need to consider for future also. Update your answer with some explanation and good luck

Comment: You still have explained nothing

Comment: Thank you! I've tried ashish's example - it works! Sorry for delaying. I've never used AsyncTask before. I'll read about AsyncTask Docs then. At last, how to get more than 1 object?

Comment: I have price, adress and other rows.

Comment: mark the answer as solve so that it helps other to  to find the answer.

Comment: tvPrice = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);   
tvAdress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAdress);
How can I post object on these TextViews?

Answer (score 4):

> Can I use it without runOnUiThread for updating my UI?

YES! Please do! Remove `runOnUiThread()` and return your result to `onPostExecute()` and update `UI` there. That's why the other methods exist.

The way you have it, you are running all of your background stuff on the `UI` which defeats the purpose of `AsyncTask`.

You can simply change your class definition to pass the `int` to `onPostExecute()`

```
class GetDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, Integer>
```

then `return success` in `doInBackground()`. And check that value in `onPostExecute()` and update `UI` if success.

```
 protected void onPostExecute(Integer result)
 {
    if (result == 1)
    {
        // code to update UI
```

### Further Explanation

Be sure to read through the [AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) really well. This class was created so that you can do your heavy-lifting such as network stuff on a background `Thread` (`doInBackground()`) and update the `UI` in it's built-in methods (the other 3).

1. `onPreExecute()` can update before the task starts such as for a
   `ProgressDialg`
2. `onProgressUpdate()` can update while `doInBackground()` is still processing such as for the progress of a downloading file by calling `publishProgress()`
3. `onPostExecute()` is called when `doInBackground()` finishes to
   update anything you need when the task finishes such as dismissing a
   `ProgressDialog`

Comment: codeMagic, thanks, I've tried and made something wrong. Can you change my code.

Comment: @user3499351 I'm not going to rewrite the entire code but I gave you what you need to change, for the most part. If you are still having trouble, you can edit your post and add your new code (without changing your original code) and I will take a look. And explain what trouble you are having now with the new code.